# Increment Operator in arrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays, post-increment, pre-increment

The following code gives the output as : ccb

```
int t = 0;
char a[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
cout<<a[t]<<a[++t]<<a[++t];
```

I want to know, what actually is happening in this code which generates the specified output. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The second `++t` is __not__ guaranteed to be evaluated after the first `++t`.

Comment: @zenith, can you provide a source that states that?

Comment: @Mox The C++ standard. There is no _sequence point_ between the two `++t`s so their order of evaluation is unspecified.

Comment: @zenith, anyway saw the link. thanks for sharing. something new for me =)

Comment: @zenith I feel like this is not a good dupe. It does not justify why the (overloaded!) `<<` do not introduce sequencing.

Comment: cppreference on order of evaluation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: @zenith, there is a sequence point at `cout << a[t]` since that involves a function call. Because of the overloaded << operator, `cout << a[t] << a[++t] << a[++t]` is equivalent to `((cout << a[t]) << a[++t]) << a[++t]`. The output seen by the OP is probably caused by uninitialized value of `t` or accessing `a` out of bounds.

Comment: @RSahu Clang gives the following warning: "unsequenced modification and access to `t`".

Comment: It is unsequenced because it is something like `f(a,f(b,f(c,d)))`. But that is worth an answer IMO.

Comment: Sorry for the uninitialised t here, but I actually did initialisation...forgot to put in here...now I have edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial reaction: C++ does not guarantee the order of evaluation on a statement like

```
cout<<a[t]<<a[++t]<<a[++t];
```

You need to do something along the lines of:

```
cout<<a[t]<<a[t + 1]<<a[t + 2];
t += 3;
```

Upon further review, in response to R Sahu's comments (thanks):  The order of evaluation may actually be determinate because operator << is a function call and a function call is a sequence point.   However the order will not be as expected.   In this case the `t++` operations are executed in right-to-left order because the arguments to each function call must be evaluated before the call is made.  I.e. this statement is actually:

```
cout ( << a[t] ( << a[++t] ( << a[++t] ) ) ) ;
```

and the innermost phrase is evaluated first.

Of course the above parenthesized expression is not valid. To be technically correct I should say:

```
operator << (operator << ( operator << ( cout, a[++t]), a[++t]), a[t]);
```

but that is confusing because in order to write the expression in this form I have to reverse the order of the index operators (which is what the compiler does).

And finally in response to Baum's comments:  Even decomposing this into function calls this way does not make the call determinate because the order in which function arguments are evaluated is not specified so it could evaluate `operator << (cout, a[++t])` before evaluating `a[t]`

The solution, avoiding operations with side-effects in complex statements, is still valid.

Comment: I don't think that is correct. When an operator is overloaded, the order of evaluation is very deterministic. The output seen by the OP is probably caused by uninitialized value of `t` or accessing `a` out of bounds.

Comment: It may be deterministic, but it's not as expected.   I just tried it with VC and the arguments are evaluated right to left, so assuming starts at zero, t[0] appears last in the output.

Comment: @RSahu I do not think so. Even when the operator is overloaded, this is something like `f(f(f(cout, t), ++t), ++t)` and the evaluation of function arguments is not sequenced. But that should be explained.

Comment: No. In `operator << ( operator << ( cout, a[++t]), a[++t])` `operator << ( cout, a[++t])` is neither sequenced before nor after the `, a[++t])`.

Answer (score 0):

The order of evaluation is unspecified. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point